# jMeter graph - what is the x axis?

Tags: jmeter

I'm using the default Graph (Add > Listener > Graph Results) in jMeter.

I can see a `ms` label at the top and bottom of the y axis.

However, I don't see any labels on the x axis.

What exactly is being output on the x axis?

Answer (score 1):

The x axis is the No. of Samplers executed. See [Tutorial](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/jmeter-tutorials/how-to-analyze-graph-result-in-jmeter)

> The x-axis contains the nth sampler

Answer (score 0):

Why not use more up to date and complete web report that exists since JMeter 3.0:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html

Regarding your question :

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Graph_Results

> x-axis is time